# How to ignore grep if the line starts with # or ;

Tags: grep

Need to ignore grep if the line starts with ; or # for a specific string in a file. `file.ini` contains below line

```
output_partition_key=FILE_CREATED_DATE
```

doing a grep as below returns values `FILE_CREATED_DATE`

```
grep -w "output_partition_key" file.ini | cut -d= -f2
```

but if say the line starts with ; or # then it should not grep anything

```
;output_partition_key=FILE_CREATED_DATE
```

I tried solutions from other posts but its not working.Can anyone tell me how to achieve the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you really want is to find lines that start with `output_partition_key=`. The simplest way to do that is:

```
grep ^output_partition_key= file.ini | cut -d= -f2
```

(where `^` means "the start of a line").